# how to limit job submision depending on location or partition

Tags: linux, hpc, lsf

I am wondering if there is a way to limit the job submission depending on the location where the submission was made in HPC.

Thing is, recently a storage for a scratch disk was added. So now I have two partitions.

1. home directory
2. scratch directory

I want all the HPC users are forced to submit their jobs only in scratch directory not in home directory.

HPC is operating LSF for job scheduler. So, can I have job submission (i.e. bsub) are controlled through LSF such that only jobs submitted under the scratch directory runs in HPC?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this natively, but there is a way to customize LSF submission-time checks to reject jobs submitted from the wrong directory.  Take a look at this documentation:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_admin/chap_sub_exec_controls_lsf_admin.html

In particular, what you want to do is define an `esub` script which checks for the appropriate submission CWD.  Let's say you name your script `esub.dircheck`, it would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh 

# Reject if submission is under /home
if [[ $PWD/ = /home/* ]]; then
   echo "Job submission from /home forbidden"
   exit $LSB_SUB_ABORT_VALUE 
fi
```

Now you can place the `esub.dircheck` into `$LSF_SERVERDIR` (make sure it's executable by all).  Finally, if you want the check to happen for every job submission, set the following parameter in lsf.conf:

```
LSB_ESUB_METHOD=dircheck
```

One final note: I'm just checking that PWD has home as a prefix in the code above, but you probably need to do something a bit more sophisticated if you want to make sure that the directory you're in is under /home because there could be symbolic links that gum up the prefix check.  [Take a look at this answer for details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6435/how-to-check-if-pwd-is-a-subdirectory-of-a-given-path).